# TFS Branch Building Issues

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I am currently having a problem with the TFS build system using VS 2008 and TFS Power Tools 2008. My problem is that I have two branches for a solution, which have several projects in each including a mobile client. The build was set up prior to my arrival and creates several environments ie dev/live/testing etc and so I have simply coppied the previous MSBuild build .proj file and changed the paths referenced to the new branch. Also updating the build definition source path used in the TFS build definition.

However now I am getting an issue that is where a linked project used in the mobile client is building the wrong assembly. This I can tell because the file size differs to that of my bin folder and also the version number is incorrect to that which has been set in the project properties in VS.

Has anyone experienced this before or can think of anything I may have missed or am overlooking.

Thanks

Comment: I managed to solve this one later in the day, it was basically an issue with how the cab files were being generated by Cabwiz. Which was done automatically as part of the build process. The .inf file I was using referenced the old build files from the temp folder on the build agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this one later in the day, it was basically an issue with how the cab files were being generated by Cabwiz. Which was done automatically as part of the build process. The .inf file I was using referenced the old build files from the temp folder on the build agent - only just noticed this option sorry.